# How to change primary key of Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a sqlite database and i want to change my primarykey using room.To do it, I create a new table, copy the data from the old table to new table, drop the old table and then rename the new table to the old table.
This is my migration code:

```
private val MIGRATION_5_6: Migration = object : Migration(5, 6) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            //Change the SpeechToTextResult primaryKeys
            database.execSQL("""
               CREATE TABLE `SpeechToTextResult_copy` (
                    `source` TEXT NOT NULL,
                    `startTime` REAL NOT NULL,
                    `endTime` REAL NOT NULL,
                    `language` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                    `computeFileIndex` INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    `projectId` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                    `wordResults` TEXT NOT NULL,
                    `computeFileId` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                    PRIMARY KEY (`language`, `projectId`, `computeFileId`)
                );
                """.trimIndent())

            database.execSQL("""
                INSERT INTO `SpeechToTextResult_copy` (`source`, `startTime`, `endTime`, `language`, `computeFileIndex`, `projectId`, `wordResults`, `computeFileId`)
                    SELECT `source`, `startTime`, `endTime`, `language`, `computeFileIndex`, `projectId`, `wordResults`, `computeFileId` FROM `SpeechToTextResult`;
                """.trimIndent())

            database.execSQL("""
                DROP TABLE `SpeechToTextResult`;
                """.trimIndent())

            database.execSQL("""
                ALTER TABLE `SpeechToTextResult_copy` RENAME TO `SpeechToTextResult`;
                """.trimIndent())

        }
    }
```

I change also my entity:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["language", "projectId", "computeFileId"])
class SpeechToTextResult constructor(@NonNull var source: String,
                                     @NonNull var startTime: Float,
                                     @NonNull var endTime: Float,
                                     @NonNull var language: String,
                                     @NonNull var computeFileIndex: Int, // index position in the computeFiles List
                                     @NonNull var projectId: String,
                                     @TypeConverters(ListConverters::class)
                                     @NonNull var wordResults: List<WordResult>,
                                     @NonNull var computeFileId: Int  // index of the scene

) {

    class ListConverters {
        @TypeConverter
        fun fromWordResultList(value: List<WordResult>): String {
            val gson = Gson()
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<WordResult>>() {

            }.type
            return gson.toJson(value, type)
        }

        @TypeConverter
        fun toWordResultsList(list: String): List<WordResult> {
            val gson = Gson()
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<WordResult>>() {

            }.type
            return gson.fromJson(list, type)
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I run my app, I have this error:

> 2019-08-13 14:34:13.776 19028-19201/io.kannelle.app.dev
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
> Process: io.kannelle.app.dev, PID: 19028
> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the
> subscribe() method call. Further reading:
> https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling |
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle
> SubtitleGeneratedInfo(io.kannelle.sdk.models.SubtitleGeneratedInfo).
> Expected:
> TableInfo{name='SubtitleGeneratedInfo', columns={projectId=Column{name='projectId', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, language=Column{name='language',
> type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=2}},
> foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
> Found:
> TableInfo{name='SubtitleGeneratedInfo', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
> ...

How I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your error seems to be for a different entity than the one in your question. The error is for `SubtitleGeneratedInfo`; your question is about `SpeechToTextResult`.

Comment: Sorry!  my bad!. I resolve my problem with your help. tx